# Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: when trying to update to Rails version 4.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I started building a new application from scratch that requires rails version 4.2.2 (currently have rails -v 4.1.5 successfully installed).

After updating my rails gem in Gemfile to rails version 4.2.2 in the /Gemfile I proceed to the terminal with 'bundle update rails' only to recieve the following error:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect 
returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed 
(https://rubygems.org/gems/json-  1.8.3.gem)
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

**Approaches that I have tested out but failed:**

1) Trying to install json -v 1.8.3 in Gemfiles

2) updating the Gemfile.lock for both Rails and Json (which were originally set to early version but now read rails (= 4.2.2) and  activesupport (4.1.5)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.8, >= 1.8.3)

3) Bundle install produces the followin error as well:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "json":
  In Gemfile:
sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) ruby depends on
  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0) ruby depends on
    activesupport (>= 3.0) ruby depends on
      json (>= 1.8.3, ~> 1.8) ruby

uglifier (>= 1.3.0) ruby depends on
  json (1.8.1)
```

4) gem install rails -v 4.2.2 (into terminal)

```
   ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (= 4.2.2), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect
    returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate   
    verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

What should I do to simply update my rails version for this app?